# costmap_2d clear obstacles after every update

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am creating costmaps of highly dynamic obstacles and want it to be efficiently cleared just before every update, so that each time only the current point cloud is projected into the map and there is no trace of what was previously projected.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213832/costmap_2d-clear-obstacles-after-every-update/) by [Ishani Chatterjee](https://answers.ros.org/users/23160/ishani-chatterjee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe you can do this with the costmap layers as they are currently structured, but you could write a subclass of the obstacle_layer that clears all information from the map on every iteration.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ishani Chatterjee](https://answers.ros.org/users/23160/ishani-chatterjee/) on 2015-07-16**:
There is a protected member resetMaps(), I tried to change its scope to public and called it in the layered_costmap function that updates maps. But I can't see any topic published. Even if I reset everything to the original source code pulled from Git, it compiles and runs, but there is no topic